# How to transfer Public IP address from One project to another Project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to know if it's possible to transfer the public IP Address from one project to another in GCP.

What I am exact too?

I've created an instance under a project called ops, but now that instance has to move on to another project under development which I was able to move by converting them into an image and created a VM under development.

But I want to retain the same public IP address. How could I move the IP address from one project to another in GCP (Google Cloud Platform)?

It will be great that if someone could say in step by step.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, it's not possible to move the public IP from one project to another.

There is an open feature request for this matter [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67726921)

Comment: That link is not publicly accessible.

Comment: @kasperd the link is correct, is the public issue tracker. You have internal access therefore if you click the link it will open the internal case, if you try opening it in incognito mode you will be redirected to the public case.

Comment: Well to bad for my situation today as moved to new project and have to remap IPs everywhere in my code and devops!

Answer (score 0):

#### Move a global external IPv4 address to a different project:

gcloud alpha compute addresses move ADDRESS_NAME 
--target-project=TARGET_PROJECT 
--global

#### Move a regional external IPv4 address to a different project and assign it a new name and description in the new project:

gcloud alpha compute addresses move ADDRESS_NAME 
--target-project=TARGET_PROJECT 
--new-name=NEW_NAME 
--description=NEW_DESCRIPTION 
--region=REGION

#### Move a regional external IPv4 address to a different project:

gcloud alpha compute addresses move ADDRESS_NAME 
--target-project=TARGET_PROJECT 
--region=REGION

**NOTE: Replace the following:**

ADDRESS_NAME: the name of the IP address resource that you want to move.

TARGET_PROJECT: the name or ID of the project that you want to move the IP address to.

REGION: the region of the IP address.

NEW_NAME: a new name for the IP address resource in the new project.

NEW_DESCRIPTION: a new name for the IP address resource in the new project. If omitted, the existing description, if any, is used for the resource.